# Is there an Javascript code generator available for Umple?

Tags: javascript, umple

I'm looking for a Umple converter that would generate Javascript classes/methods from Umple, similar to what the Java code generator for Umple. I am not interested in graphical/diagram representations, just an Umple->Javascript conversion.

Comment: Have you try convert to java and after convert to javascript?

Comment: I have not, and I'm not sure of how reliable this would be.

Comment: you can do, if there is no way to convert umple to javascript, is more accessible convert umple to java and after try convert java to javascript class

Answer (score 0):

Umple doesn't currently have a builtin Javascript generator. Tools such as those listed at https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-automatically-convert-Java-to-JavaScript look as though they might do a good job of allowing Umple to indirectly generate Javascript.

Umple issue 1384 https://github.com/umple/umple/issues/1384 is outstanding on this matter.